# Excel formula that shows only the first row value if repeated in the same column

Tags: excel-formula

I'd like to know if there is a way to show in Excel the first row value if in a column there is a repeated sequence, if the value changes, populate it with that new value until it changes again to avoid repeated values to show. I'm sorry for the poor explanation.

I've tried using the following formula =INDEX(A2:A300,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(B2:B300,C2),0)) But received a "value not available" error

For example:

*Raw Data*

```
  event_time                      x1

 Nov 22, 2023 @ 10:24:30.001       1 
 Nov 22, 2023 @ 10:25:00.007       1
 Nov 22, 2023 @ 10:25:30.017       1 
 Nov 22, 2023 @ 10:26:00.017       2
 Nov 22, 2023 @ 10:26:30.017       2
 Nov 22, 2023 @ 10:27:00.017       0
 Nov 22, 2023 @ 10:27:30.017       0
 Nov 22, 2023 @ 10:28:00.017       1
 Nov 22, 2023 @ 10:28:30.017       1
```

*Expected Output*

```
     event_time                  x1

Nov 22, 2023 @ 10:24:30.001       1
Nov 22, 2023 @ 10:26:00.017       2
Nov 22, 2023 @ 10:27:00.017       0
Nov 22, 2023 @ 10:28:00.017       1
```

Comment: `=UNIQUE(A1:B11)` ?

Comment: Hi @P.b, that will only show the unique values e.g. 

Nov 22, 2023 @ 10:24:30.001       1
Nov 22, 2023 @ 10:26:00.017       2
Nov 22, 2023 @ 10:27:00.017       0

But will ignore the rest. What I need is to output the first number of a sequence of the repeated numbers even though previously had that number. 
Raw data 
x1
1
1
2
0
1
1
1
1
1
1
0
0
0
1
1

Desired Output
1
2
0
1
0
1

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this formula:

```
=LET(d,A1:B9,
checkDiff,MAP(SEQUENCE(ROWS(d)),INDEX(d,,2),VSTACK("",DROP(INDEX(d,,2),-1)),LAMBDA(x,a,b,a<>b)),
FILTER(d,checkDiff))
```

`checkDiff` compares each column B value with the next row - if not equal it returns `true`, if equal `false`.

The result is used to filter the whole list.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=LET(range,A1:B9,
     b,DROP(range,,1),
CHOOSEROWS(range,TOCOL(ROW(range)/(b<>(VSTACK("",DROP(b,-1)))),2)))
```